# Replicate content across IIS farm, *not* on a domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, replication, dfs

What's the best way of replicating web content across an IIS web farm where the servers are not on a domain?

Most people seem to recommend DFS for this type of scenario, but I understand that relies on AD to work, and running a domain here is not an option.

If this were unix, I could happily do this with RSYNC, but would have to go down the cygwin approach to achieve that here, and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: The best way iyss to install a domain. This is what MS hsoting recommedation (http://www.iis.net) says. Scalble hosting approach outside of MS recommendations without in depth knowledge is not a decent approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as the machines all have an account with the same username and password, you could just do this with robocopy in a scheduled task.